# Binding in Nested List Boxes to multiple classes

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

I'm making a nested listed box , basically because I need to bind multiple classes in a single list box , which I'm not able to do and hence the nested listed box.

Here's what I do in the XAML page :

```
<ListBox Name="abcd" Margin="10,0,30,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Title}"     SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Height="486" Width="404" FontSize="20">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="380" Height="140">
                            <Grid  >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding cdata}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                                <ListBox Name="ab" ItemsSource="{Binding Description}" FontSize="14">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Width="380" Height="100">
                                                <Grid>
                                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding cdata}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>                            
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

where ListBox "abcd" has to be bound with class title and "ab" to the class Description.Both the classes have just one string field , "cdata".

In the xaml.cs I do :

```
abcd.ItemsSource=from article in root.openfooty.news.article
                          select new Classes.Title 
                             { 
                                  cdata = article.title.cdata
                             };

       ab.ItemSource = from article in root.openfooty.news.article
                            select new Classes.Description
                              { 
                                  cdata = article.description.cdata
                              };
```

binding with "abcd" works fine but with "ab" it says "the nam ab doesnt exist in the current context"

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :D

Comment: In the Csharp code, you are binding both the listboxes to same Title class and the same article.title.cdata ??

Comment: Sorry. that was a typo , I'm binding it to another class here's the code.

    ab.ItemSource = from article in root.openfooty.news.article
                            select new Classes.Description
                            {
                                cdata = article.description.cdata
                            };

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a single class like this

```
public class TitleDescription
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

and try the databinding ?

```
abcd.ItemsSource=from article in root.openfooty.news.article
                      select new Classes.TitleDescription 
                         { 
                              title = article.title.cdata,
                              description = article.description.cdata
                         };
```

And have only one list box like this

```
<ListBox Name="abcd" Margin="10,0,30,0" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Height="486" Width="404" FontSize="20">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="380" Height="140">
                        <Grid  >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```